# How to disable the approval process in the Opportunity object for certain user?

Tags: lightning, opportunity, approval-process, classic

How to disable the approval process in the Opportunity object for certain user?

Even if the users press the submit for approval the Opportunity record to became automatically approved.

Please advise how it can be achieved?

Comment: why not create a step and in step criteria where you can check if profile or custom permission  is not equal to whatever you need then approve the record else assign an approver

Answer (score 1):

You can create a queue and add required users who are eligible to submit for approval. This queue can be added as Initial Submitter during Approval Process configuration.